# Does the GNU General Public License (GPL) allow release under a different version of the GPL?

Tags: gpl

I'm currently modifying code released under GPL v2.0, and I'm wondering if the GPL allows release under a different version, say, GPL v3.0 or if it has to remain under the same version as the original.

Comment: Is it your code? Or is it somebody else's code released under GPL v2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on how the license was written.

Many GPL v2.0 projects (such as Linux) are licensed under GPL v2.0. Period. No 'or later'.

This is described in the FSF wiki:

> Works under the GPLv2 are only compatible with the GPLv3 if they are upgraded manually by the copyright holder(s), or if the work was originally licensed in the manner section 9 of the GPLv2 described:
>
> > If the Program specifies a version number of this License which applies to it and "any later version", you have the option of following the terms and conditions either of that version or of any later version published by the Free Software Foundation.

If a GPL licensed software project doesn't say *or later* or, is otherwise incompatible with the various additional grants (such as the patent grant).

The compatibility is further described in the [gnu gpl compatibility matrix](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility) which shows that if the license is "GPL v2 only" it cannot be relicensed under GPL v3.

There are projects that say GPL v2 or later.  There are other projects that say GPL v2 *only*.  It is a matter of reading the license for the project.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. You can only re-license a copyrighted work if all copyright holders agree.

Note, however, that it is perfectly possible for all copyright holders to agree to release the copyrighted work under more than one license. In particular, it is perfectly possible to release a copyrighted work unter the GPL2 *and* GPL3, or even under "the GPL2 or any later version of the GPL".

But, if the piece of software you are talking about is released under the GPL2, then it is released under the GPL2, period.